# jquery template error $(...).tmpl is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-templates

I want use jquery template but it doesn't work correctly.
here's my mark up Html. it's simple but i confuse why it doesn't work Correctly

```
 <head runat="server">
    <script src="Resource/Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Resource/Scripts/jquery-tmpl.js"></script>    
            <script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" >
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>${urlPic}</label></td>
                        <td><label>${name}</label></td>
                        <td><label>>${count}</label</td>
                        <td><label>${price}</label></td>
                        <td><label >${sum}</label></td>
                    </tr>
              </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                            var data = [{ urlPic: "abc.jpg", name: "Tom", count: "3", price: "3000000
        0", sum: "40000000" } ];

    // below line raise errro                   
                         $("#myTmpl").tmpl(data).appendTo("#baskettbl2");
                    });
            </script>
  </head>
```

and here's my html

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table id="baskettbl2"><table>
</form>
</body>
```

I get this Error:

```
TypeError: $(...).tmpl is not a function
```

EDIT: 
I found it doesn't work only on first request. this template is in my Master Page. When load Default. it doesn't work. but when click to another page, it works! what's the problem? i'm  really confused

Comment: Can you show how you include your JS files?

Comment: yes i edited my post. add js files

Comment: Did you check that jquery-tmpl.js is loaded properly? and check that your page does not override the $.tmpl

Comment: I copy my above code in Raw aspx file and it works!!! @KhanhTo

Comment: Check it using network capture to see if any 404 errors appear

Comment: so thanks dear @KhanhTo , but what's "network Capture. I get the error by Firebug add-on. it doesn't said to me a bout any 404 error.

Comment: what's the benefitial of using net capture software. how it can help me. can you give me a good link to understand it? thank

Comment: @KhanhTo i add Edit paragraph on post. tnx

Comment: @Edalat: network capture is a built-in feature in majority of browser. For example, in IE you click F12 and choose network tab. Network capture allows us to see the requests, responses between browser and server, inspect request/response body, header, status code,...

Comment: @KhanhTo: so thanks but i user and ie>f12>net, in both of them there isn't any 404 Error; and now i get same Error for this method $.parsJSON(result.d); i'm confused. i don't know what can i do. how debug it. where's problem. :(

Comment: @Edalat: well then you need to check if there is any other library on the page that override the $. (as I know, prototype also uses $)

Comment: @KhanhTo right is with you! i use JQuery insteed of $, and it works!

Comment: I believe that some other library overrides the $. Fortunately, jquery and $ refer to the same object in memory. If you have time, you should track down which one is overriding.

Comment: @KhanhTo:  I comment this, (function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // amd. register as anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        // browser globals.
        factory(jquery);
    }
}(function ($) {

    var pluses = /\+/g;

    function raw(s) {
        return s;
    } and now it works. so thanks. put your comment as answer to get reputation. tnx again...

Comment: I posted as an answer, thanks.

Comment: @KhanhTo how can i add beneath custom function to my Jquery.js fiel. could you take me a good line. tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to do 2 checks:

- Use browser built-in network capture to see if the libraries are loaded properly.
- Check if another library or script on the page overrides the $ variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had enclosed these custom function(belong to working with cookies) to my jquery.js file and it override my $ char. i Comment these lines and error solved

```
    (function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // amd. register as anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        // browser globals.
        factory(jquery);
    }
}

(function ($) {

    var pluses = /\+/g;

    function raw(s) {
        return s;
    }

    function decoded(s) {
        return decodeuricomponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
    }

    function converted(s) {
        if (s.indexof('"') === 0) {
            // this is a quoted cookie as according to rfc2068, unescape
            s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
        }
        try {
            return config.json ? json.parse(s) : s;
        } catch (er) { }
    }

    var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

        // write
        if (value !== undefined) {
            options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);

            if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new date();
                t.setdate(t.getdate() + days);
            }

            value = config.json ? json.stringify(value) : string(value);

            return (document.cookie = [
                config.raw ? key : encodeuricomponent(key),
                '=',
                config.raw ? value : encodeuricomponent(value),
                options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toutcstring() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by ie
                options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
                options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
            ].join(''));
        }

        // read
        var decode = config.raw ? raw : decoded;
        var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
        var result = key ? undefined : {};
        for (var i = 0, l = cookies.length; i < l; i++) {
            var parts = cookies[i].split('=');
            var name = decode(parts.shift());
            var cookie = decode(parts.join('='));

            if (key && key === name) {
                result = converted(cookie);
                break;
            }

            if (!key) {
                result[name] = converted(cookie);
            }
        }

        return result;
    };

    config.defaults = {};

    $.removecookie = function (key, options) {
        if ($.cookie(key) !== undefined) {
            // must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
            $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

}));
```

Comment: Could you tell in more details about your solution? Doe not actually look clear.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas yes. why not

Comment: check if the $ is overridden, search for noConflict in solution and check what character overrides $ and use it. example in my case rather than using $ if i use _$.tmpl() then it works.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, just check the 'jquery.tmpl.min.js' reference must be added, [here the link file](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl).

Answer (score 0):

check if the $ is overridden, search for noConflict in solution and check what character overrides $ and use it. example in my case rather than using $ if i use _$.tmpl() then it works.